# nmap launched on my LAN put my DSL connection down?

Tags: networking, router, adsl, nmap, dsl-modem

Today I made some tests with nmap on my home network.
I launched

```
nmap -n -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

The scan completed and gave expected output.

Strangely enough, after the scan has completed, I have lost my internet connection. I logged in the modem and verified that DSL link was down. I immediately thought the scan made my DSLmodem-router-AP crash, so I waited some time and rebooted the modem. I don't know why but even after the reboot, the modem reported DSL link down for several minutes. More precisely, during these minutes of link down the link state moved back and forth between `activating` and `handshaking` states. After some minutes the link became active.

Needless to say, everything was working fine before the scan and besides the DSL link requires far less time for going up under normal circumstances.

How can it be? Is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Is your home network on the range scanned? I only ask as I know some ISP's have weird setups with the same class IP's on the other side of the modem and this could end up being routed out onto the ISP's network and them blocking you for this.

Comment: @djsmiley2k yes the range scanned is my home network.